# Wordpress get_post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to retrieve url to last post image with `get_post_meta` method, but I don't know how, and what paramaters are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `get_post_meta` inside Wordpress allows you to obtain custom values from custom fields that you have placed in a specific post. Perhaps you have a vote box, or a mood box that users can place information inside. get_post_meta lets you obtain those stored values from inside the Wordpress system.

`get_post_meta` lets you utilize the custom fields functionality of Wordpress:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Here are some examples of the usage of get_post_meta inside Wordpress:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_meta_Function_Examples

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know either but this is the first result for googling `wordpress get_post_meta`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

> **Usage**:
>   `<?php $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I've written some simple templating functions that enable you to use the meta data (custom data) in your theme.  You can write a template function for any meta data key/value pair, and render it in a theme file like so:

```
<?php the_meta_templates($meta_data_keys) ?>
<?php the_template_for($meta_data_key) ?>
```

Feel free to check out the basic functions from [github](https://github.com/abecoffman/Wordpress-Meta-Templates) and give them a try.  You'll need to add them to your themes functions.php file.