# Confused with if statement which doesn't have any 'verb' (e.g ==, !=, etc.)

Tags: php, if-statement

I understand that if else staments should say stuff like:

if dog equals one, do this.

```
if (dog==1)
```

But in the following php code it seems like it is saying

If dog then do this (if dog what?)

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true) ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <img class="thumb" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true) ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I feel like it is like a sentence missing its verb.

Can anyone explain that to me in plain English?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262421/wordpress-get-post-meta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression used as the condition of an if statement can be anything. Nobody forces you to use a comparison operator The value of the expression is converted into a boolean, and used as the condition.

```
$foo = true;
if ($foo) // quite valid

function bar() {
    return false;
}
if (bar()) // also valid

if ("hello") // PHP automatically casts types, so a string is also fine

if (1 + 1) // any expression will do
```

For an explanation on how different values are converted into booleans, [see the manual](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

If you feel *completely* lost without one of your "verbs", you can always imagine a `== true` at the end of every if statement. Just don't write that into your code, because `== true` just looks silly.

Comment: +1 The last sentence should be bold. Sorry if *you* can't wrap your mind around expressions and booleans, but no need to irritate those who do.

Answer (score 2):

The if needs a boolean. The `==` operator returns if something is true or false, but a function, in this case `get_post_meta` can also return `true` or `false`.

It can even contain a variable. This is trivial when the variable is a boolean, but if the value is a string this will also work. the string `"1"` will be evaluated as true, as well as the string `"this is a string"`. This will be confusing when the string is for instance `"false"` which is also `true` (as opposed to `false`, the boolean).

Answer (score 0):

The if condition is fulfilled, when the return value of get_post_meta is true.

Answer (score 0):

`if`s have an implicit `== true`, so `if(dog)` is equivalent to `if(dog == true)`

Answer (score 0):

if (the result of this function is true) then output this to the html

Answer (score 0):

when you have the following

```
if ($a)
```

This is true when $a is not evaluated to FALSE.

For example, 0 or false will not pass this test.

Answer (score 0):

if *this post have thumbnail image* then do ...

Answer (score 0):

here the if condition will pass when get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true) is -

true, 1, a non empty string or a non empty array.

even if the expression doesn't return a boolean, php will evaluate it as boolean